# iOS Calculating number don't show decimals

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, int, decimal

When I calculate with numbers in my App, there are no decimals in my output!
this is the code I am using:

```
    int Vijfhonderdmeter = [_VijfHonderd.text intValue];
int vijftienhonderdmeter = [_vijftienhonderd.text intValue];

int vijfdeeldrie = vijftienhonderdmeter / 3;

int puntentotaal = Vijfhonderdmeter + vijfdeeldrie;
_PuntenTotaal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",puntentotaal];
```

The real output should be 87,18667, but my `_Puntentotaal` label only shows 87.

Has anyone got a solution?

By the way:

```
(_VijfHonderd.text intValue = 44.05).
(_vijftienhonderd.text intValue = 129.41).
```

Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float)

Answer (score 2):

3 problems:

1) You are using integer division with integer value. If you want floating point numbers you need to floating point values and do floating point division:

```
double Vijfhonderdmeter = [_VijfHonderd.text doubleValue];
double vijftienhonderdmeter = [_vijftienhonderd.text doubleValue];

double vijfdeeldrie = vijftienhonderdmeter / 3.0;
```

2) You are formatting the result using `%d`. Use `%f` with the `double` values.

3) Use `NSNumberFormatter`, not `stringWithFormat:` to format the numbers. This will ensure they look correct for all users based on their locale.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always return a non decimal value as you are operating with `int` datatype.

```
int Vijfhonderdmeter = [_VijfHonderd.text intValue]; here you are getting a non decimal value & later also you are operating it with other non-decimal values. To get decimal values, you should use `double` or `float` datatype.
```

For now,try this:

```
float Vijfhonderdmeter = [_VijfHonderd.text floatValue];
float vijftienhonderdmeter = [_vijftienhonderd.text floatValue];

float vijfdeeldrie = vijftienhonderdmeter / 3;

float puntentotaal = Vijfhonderdmeter + vijfdeeldrie;
_PuntenTotaal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",puntentotaal];
```

Refer [this link](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/primitives.html) for more knowledge about premitive datatypes in objective-C

Comment: That won't work either.  Int divided by Int will still be int.  Change it to `/ 3.0` or `/3.0f`.

Comment: @Putz1103 No, the code is correct. `float / int` is done as `float`.

Comment: Ahh yes, my bad.  I was still reading the op's int primitives, not the updates float primitives.

Comment: I would, but you didn't explain at all why your code works and the op's does not.  The correct code only helps this once.  Understanding the error and why it is wrong helps down the road.

Comment: @Putz1103. Nice gesture. Respect ... _/\\_ ... Edited my answer. Have a look at it & let me know if still something can be added