# What did I do wrong with calculating percent in processing?

Tags: processing

I was writing a simple processing script that does an random boolean and counts how oft its 1 instead of 0.

then I added an counter of the total amount an random is done.
i wanted to use that for claculating the percentage of the 1ns.
anything works fine to this point.
then I wanted to do the calculating. it shows 0 no matter what i do.
the code goes like

```
bool r; //boolean for random
int t;  //t fr true or 1
int f;  //f for false or 0
int cnt; //cnt for total count
float p; //for the percentage
Void draw(){
 r = int(random(2));
 if (r==0){int(f++);}
 if (r==1){int(t++);}
 if (r<100){cnt++;}
 p = t / cnt * 100; //calculating percentage.
 text(p,10,100);   //draws text on sceen at x=10 and y=100 but it always draws 0
}
```

Whats is wrong with that? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is `t` maybe not initialized when `r==0`? same for count when `r<100`

Comment: i have an text() for all variables and all do what theyre supposed to

Comment: Can you write `((float) (t /cnt)) *100.0` because it calculates `t/cnt` with `int`. So the result of `t/cnt` is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is this problem: [Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float)

So you can write something like that:

```
(t * 100.0f)/cnt
```

Comment: Does this work for you? When not you can put a breakpoint to `text` and check `p` maybe your `text` function is wrong.

Comment: thanks that worked out nicely. i didnt know abot Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?

Comment: text worked allright as i commented earlier i use text way more than one time and it works