# C double not working as expect

Tags: c

I am writing some where I need to divide 29 by 10. But when I do so and store it in a double, it outputs 2.0000 instead of 2.9. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
double a = 29/10;

output: 2.0000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `double` works as expected, it's just that you are not assigning it an expression of type `double`.

What you assign it is an `int`, a result of dividing `29`, an `int`, by `10`, an `int`. This is `2`, because the remainder is discarded when you divide integers.

Changing `29` to `29.0` or `10` to `10.0` will fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`29 / 10` performs integer division. Result is 2 (with a remainder of 9).

Try `(double)29 / 10` or `29.0 / 10`.

Comment: For clarity, it would be better to write `(double)29 / 10`

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical C mistake: you are doing an integer division and requesting a floating point result.

You should do a floating point division with

```
double a = 29.0/10.0;
```

You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) if you want to discover all details about floating point operations.