# Why is this code in C not returning a decimal value like expected?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 355/113;
    printf("%f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this returning 3.0000 instead of 3.141592?

Comment: An excerpt from [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users): _Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer_ I Googled the words ___C division return int and not float___ which led me to this SO question: [Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float) Does it, or any of its duplicate questions, provide an answer for you?

Comment: Even when you fix the constants to become floating point, the answer is 3.141593 rather than 3.141592 — the value is approximately 3.1415929, compared with π ≈ 3.1415926538979…

Comment: @Abra ... I tried searching on Google. I haven't completely wrapped my head around the terms in programming so I guess I didn't use the right key words when searching because I wasn't finding what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The division is being performed using integer arithmetic and the result of the division is converted to a float. If you want float division use floating point literals such as 355.0 and 113.0.

Comment: Strictly, `355.0` is a `double` literal; `355.0F` is the `float` equivalent (and `355.0L` is the `long double` equivalent).  In this context, the difference doesn't matter; in some contexts, it does.  See also C11 [§6.4.4.2 Floating constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Detail: Strictly, `355.0` is a `double` constant, a _decimal-floating-constant_- not literal.  C has _string literals_ and _compound literals_.  In C literals can have their address taken, not so with constants.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica — consider my wrists suitably slapped.  In colloquial C, they're literals.  And the type of `355.0` is `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agree about colloquial C.  It was _"strictly"_ that stepped passed casual, hence the comment.  Always enjoy your work.

Answer (score 3):

Because `355/113` is **integer division**, not **floating-point division**. The decimal portion is getting truncated off before the result is assigned to the `float`.

Try this instead:

```c
float a = 355.0f / 113.0f;
```

Comment: I think it's important to mention that the reason it's integer division is that, in C, types are computed inside-out, or bottom-up. The sort of division done by `/` is decided *only* based on the "intrinsic" type of its arguments, not on the "expected type" of its context.

Comment: What is the 'f' for? It works without it.

Comment: @ShubhRoy: The `F` suffix denotes a `float` constant; no suffix on a floating point constant denotes a `double` constant, and an `L` suffix denotes a `long double` constant.  The case of `F` and `L` is not significant (but `l` and `1` are easily confused; always use the upper-case letters).  See also C11 [§6.4.4.2 Floating constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2).

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing integers but you want `float`, so just do this:

```
int main()
{

  float a = 355/(float)113;

  printf("%f", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've understood the problem. I just need to know how this works. Could I do this with any other data type?

Comment: You can perform a "casting" with types, but when you do that, depending on the type, you can lose data