# Floating value query in C

Tags: c

I want to get the answer of r^(a1/b1) but my code is not giving the correct output, can anyone help?

```
int main()
{
  float rat;
  float r=2.0;
  int a1=2;
  int b1=4;
  rat= pow(r,(a1/b1));
  printf("%f",rat);
    
return 0;
}
```

My output is coming as `1.000000`
while it should come `1.414000`.
And my condition is that I have to take `a1` and `b1` as integer values.

Comment: `(a1/b1)` is zero.  Remember, `a1` and `b1` are integers, so you're doing integer division.  If you don't want that, cast one of them to `double` to force floating point division.

Comment: When dividing two integers with each other the result will be an integer, just case one of them to float and you should be fine. ((float)a1/b1)

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: use `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

The `a1` and `b1` are integers. When you are dividing this `(a1/b1)` you will get the output as zero. So internally the `pow` function will take it as `2^0`which is `1` and this is the output you are getting here.

So the change you have to do is either you cast the `a1` to `float` or `b1` to `float`. Then this will work.

I will post a working code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  float rat;
  float r = 2.0;
  int a1 = 2;
  int b1 = 4;
  rat = pow (r, ((float)a1 / b1)); //Casting the a1 to float
  printf ("%f", rat);
  return 0;
}
```

Output `1.414214` will be printed out. Here as you can see I cast the `a1` to `float`. The same casting you can apply it for `b1` also. This will also work.

For more info you can go [Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float)

Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: Little reason to use `float` here, risk truncation and then use `double` math with `2.0`, `pow()` and `printf ("%f", rat);`.  Suggest dropping `float` and using `double`.