# why I didn't get any floating points?

Tags: c, printf, decimal, scanf

I am writing a program to calculate an average fuel consumption from the given total distance (integer value) traveled (in km) and spent fuel (in liters).

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int distance;
    int noOfLiters;
    printf("Enter The distance:");
    scanf("%d",&distance);
    printf("Enter The Fuel Spent:");
    scanf("%d",&noOfLiters);

    float avgFuelConsumption = noOfLiters/distance;

    printf("Average Fuel Consumption :  %f", avgFuelConsumption);
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter The distance:50
Enter The Fuel Spent:5
Average Fuel Consumption :  0.000000
```

The Average Fuel Consumption should be `0.1`, but I got 0, Why?

Comment: Cast one of the numbers to be `float` when you divide. Integer division of small/large will always give you zero...

Comment: Because of the types. An int divided by another int will use integer division, throwing away the remainder. You must cast either noOfLiters or distance to float first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float

Comment: Or use floating point values for the `distance` and `noOfLiters`.

Comment: I Got It Now , thank you

Comment: On another note, unless you have specific requirements there's almost never any need to use `float` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
float distance;
float noOfLiters;
```

Comment: "total distance (integer value) " this is given , so I must only have yo change noOfLiters, Thank you

Comment: That's not enough, the conversion specifiers in `scanf` need to be changed too.

Comment: If he doesn't change it, he'll get an error, I thought you'd notice it